# Script recording using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using mozilla firefox browser to record a script using jmenter. I have set the browser proxy settings correctly. But, when I start recording the script, the webpage of an application is not getting loaded completely with all the content and correct alignment. Why? Could some one help me out here please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that this is due to incorrect HTTPS configuration, try importing JMeter's self-signed certificate into Firefox like:

Choose the following options:

- Tools / Options
- Advanced / Certificates
- View Certificates
- Authorities
- Import …
- Browse to the JMeter launch directory, and click on the file 
  `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt`, press Open
- Click View and check that the certificate details agree with the ones displayed by the JMeter Test Script Recorder
- If OK, select "Trust this CA to identify web sites", and press OK
- Close dialogs by pressing OK as necessary

More information: **HTTPS recording and certificates** section of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) JMeter User Manual chapter.

---

You can also consider an alternative solution of recording a JMeter test: use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), in this case you won't need to worry about proxies and certificate, just follow your test scenario steps and they will be recorded automatically.